# Trying to create a text file log using java

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and trying to create a log file. The code I have written works at sending the message and the time to a text file . But every time I send another message it just records over the previous. I want to have a list of messages and times just not the latest one.

```
public void run () {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println( "You voted " + message + " You the best") ;
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
                out.append(message + "\n");
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); // or PST, MID, etc ...
                Date now = new Date();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("           yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss ");
                df.setTimeZone(tz);
                String currentTime = df.format(now);
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat().format( new Date() ); 

                FileWriter aWriter = new FileWriter("test.txt", true);
                aWriter.write(currentTime + "   "  + "\n");
                aWriter.flush();
                aWriter.close();

                out.write(message);
                out.close();
                everyoneMessage(message);

            } // close while
            }catch(Exception ex) {ex .printStackTrace();}
        } // close run
    }// close inner class
```

Comment: Look at java.util.logging.Logger, when you have the hang of that check out slf4j

Comment: Use a logging library (e.g. log4j) and do not forget to put the close statements in `finally` blocks;

Answer (score 1):

Change `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));`

to

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true)); 
               // true means append to the end of the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Logging for java is best practiced via log4j.
as a back-end java programmer i never had a situation where i needed to implement a logger and not use log4j.

You should check it out:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

And find yourself some simple tutorials online. there are countless ones with a simple google search.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're reinitializing your `BufferedWriter` through the loop.  Move that code block to outside of the loop.  Alternatively, you can use this construct for `FileWriter` which [allows the file to be appended to](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true));
```